# how to validate credit card info(billing, card number etc) through authorize.net?

Tags: php, validation, credit-card, verification, authorize.net

I'm not just talking about validating the card numbers' format, im talking about actually sending it through authorize.net(for instance) to validate the card info.  Is there a way to do this without a transaction through authorize.net?

I already saw [this link](https://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/The-Authorize-Net-Developer-Blog/Validating-Credit-Card-Information-Part-1-of-3-Credit-Card/ba-p/6956) and its not what I'm looking for.  I want to send the credit card info to authorize.net for validation/verification, not just validate the format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. The only way to know a credit card is valid is to process a transaction. Only then is the bank contacted to validate the credit card.

FYI, I am the author of the article you linked to.

Comment: Wow really?  Thanks for answering, and its an honor to have you answer my question lol.

Comment: If you are using AIM method you need to send a Auth_Capture request via curl. Then check the response code (success/fail).

Comment: @Brian Actually you want to do an auth_only. That way the customer is never actually charged.

Comment: It depends on what the project calls for. The default is Auth_Capture. More info on x_type: https://support.authorize.net/authkb/index?page=content&id=A510&pmv=print&impressions=false

Comment: No it doesn't. If you just want to validate a credit card you don't want to charge it against it *ever*. That's one of the reasons auth_only exists.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing an auth_only (pre-auth), you need to make sure to either do a subsequent capture or void to capture or release the funds. Processors frown upon you if you rack up too many open authorizations left open more than a certain amount of days.

Have you thought of doing a zero dollar authorization for this? I believe if you send a 0 for the amount and pass the AVS field values, you may do a ZDA.

[AIM API](http://developer.authorize.net/guides/AIM/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm#href=B_APIFields.html&single=true) - Search for Zero